# avoid fixing mysql insert commands after adding another colomn

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql insert command has the following format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

Let us say that I have the insert command on multiple php files or on multiple classes or objects. After a year, I decide to add a new column to that table. The previous insert command will stop working and I have to update all my insert commands in my script with adding a new column to my insert command.

Are there any best practices or techniques that I can use to avoid updating my insert command every time I add a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add new column with default value. So you will need to edit only that INSERTs which it is necessary to.

Also it will help you to deploy your new database schema, because in this case your old app code will be perfectly working with modified schema. And you can deploy schema and on second step deploy code without any downtime.